# How to I add a line break after each full stop in php, when pulling text from the database?

Tags: php, expression, addition, line-breaks

I have text within one of my tables which is a long description, but the text is all clumped together. I need a way for PHP to find each full stop and add a line break after it, so I can treat the description as a list.

A better solution would be to add an

tag at the start of each sentence, and have each sentence finish with a

so I can actually add bullet points.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) function to replace each occurrance of a full stop with a full stop plus a line break.  If you are rendering HTML, a line break is probably the `<br/>` tag.

Comment: I've tried doing the str_replace() method but it doesn't seem to be working, can anyone show any examples by any chance?

Comment: Ah ok got it working, had to just find the character then replace it.

$search  = array('.', ':');
$replace = array('.<br /><br />', '');
 
echo $longDesc = str_replace($search, $replace, $desc);